# How can I access class variable from method JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, spotify

I'm new in `javascript` and I'm trying to create a simple class with some method but I have an issue and I can't figure out what I'm doing bad.

```
var SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

const my_client_id = "xxx";
const my_secret = "xxx";

class Spotify {
    constructor() {
         this.spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
            redirectUri: 'http://localhost:8081/spotifyCallback',
            clientId: my_client_id,
            clientSecret: my_secret
        }); 
    }

    connect() {
        console.log(this.spotifyApi.redirectUri);
        return spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL('teststate', ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email']);
    };
}
```

Here, when I try to log into console spotifyApi.redirectUri, I get undefined (tried with and without the this keyword).

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `connect`?

Comment: @CertainPerformance `var Spotify = require("./services/spotify.js").Spotify
var spotify = new Spotify(); 
[...]
app.get('/spotify', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(spotify.connect());
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you are accessing objects are incorrect. Look at below code and output.

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');
const my_client_id = "xxx";
const my_secret = 'xxx';
const redirectUri='http://localhost:8081/spotifyCallback';

    class Spotify {       
        constructor(my_client_id, my_secret, redirectUri) {
            this.spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
                clientId: my_client_id,
                clientSecret: my_secret,
                redirectUri: redirectUri
            });
        }        
        connect() {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(spotify.spotifyApi._credentials,null,4));
            console.log(this.spotifyApi._credentials.redirectUri);       
            return this.spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL(['user-read-private', 'user-read-email'],'teststate');
        };
    }

    //Instantiate
    const spotify = new Spotify(my_client_id, my_secret ,redirectUri);
    const connectObject = spotify.connect();
```

OutPut:

```
    {
    "clientId": "xxx",
    "clientSecret": "xxx",
    "redirectUri": "http://localhost:8081/spotifyCallback"
    }
    http://localhost:8081/spotifyCallback
```

Also you have not passed the correct parameters for `createAuthorizeURL` . Have a look at signautre abouve  and at [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to follow up on OP's issue. I'll admit I don't have much time. I read the source a bit, and I wondered if you could replace `this.spotifyApi._credentials.redirectUri` with `this.spotifyApi.getRedirectURI()` (the getter being defined there : https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/blob/master/src/spotify-web-api.js#L48)

Answer (score 3):

This is because your lib (https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) uses `redirectUri` as option when instantiating it, but does not expose it as an attribute.

If you still need it, put `redirectUri` in a class attribute with something like this :

```
const SpotifyWebApi = require('spotify-web-api-node');

class Spotify {
    constructor(my_client_id, my_secret) {
         this.redirectUri = 'http://localhost:8081/spotifyCallback';
         this.spotifyApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
            redirectUri: this.redirectUri,
            clientId: my_client_id,
            clientSecret: my_secret
        }); 
    }

    connect() {
        console.log(this.redirectUri);
        return this.spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL('teststate', ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email']);
    };
}

const my_client_id = "xxx";
const my_secret = "xxx";

// Now you can instantiate your class with this :
const spotify = new Spotify(my_client_id, my_secret);
const yourToken = spotify.connect();
```

I edited my answer with some good practices (adding constructor arguments, using `this`,...)

Comment: Okok thanks you! And if i wan't to use the object spotifyApi into the connect method, i should use this.spotifyApi ?

Comment: You need to use `this.spotifyApi` actually. I edited my answer. Also it would be better to pass `my_client_id` and `my_secret ` as parameters in the constructor.

Comment: @Seblor, do you mean spotify have this way to instantiating and setting the options?  If i pass the simple object in constructor and try to access the properties i am able to read it.

Comment: The API you are using has a class (that your named "SpotifyWebApi") which needs an object as argument when constructing it. This object contains all the options it needs : "redirectUri", "clientId" and "clientSecret". However, you might not be able to access them from the resulting object, it depends on what the APi does in the constructor. If you want to have variables that you can access in your whole class instance, you need to put them in a property with something like `this.yourProperty = "yourValue"`.

Comment: Okay, Just wondering how that works for clientId and other paramerters. Looking at source of of spotify-web-api.js i cannot set any difference the way it is trying to access and use these options
https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node/blob/master/src/spotify-web-api.js

Comment: @Seblor `return this.spotifyApi.createAuthorizeURL('teststate', ['user-read-private', 'user-read-email']);`
This line doesn't work, I can't access the method of the spotifyApi object, even with the keyword this. I get a weird error `TypeError: scopes.join is not a function`

Comment: I think your clientId and clientSecret will also go undefined, please check

Comment: @Sohan Yes, i can't access any variable of spotifyApi when i'm into the connect method

Comment: Maybe i'm not doing it the right way, I have an index.js file with the instance of my Spotify class. In the same file, i'll catch a post on localhost/spotify.
When I get this request, I'm calling the connect method of the spotify class which is in my spotify.js file, with my class declaration. this method will redirect the user on the spotify page, then on a callback function. All i want is an access to the same instance of  spotiftApi object IN the class/method, and IN the functions... I don't know if i'm clear, i'm new and my english is not quite good... @Sohan

Comment: Look at my answer above. It should solve your issues.